# how to use a function which returns value to ng-model using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wan to call a function which returns value and I want to use that value as ng-model.
the returned value from function should be displayed in a dialog.

I see my dialog empty - No Data.

here is my code:
my-dialog is a directive to show dialog which accepts templateurl and ng-model.

```
 <my-dialog my-dlg-template-url="/app/ScheduleDlg.html" ng-model="ViewSchedule">
            <button ng-click="openDialog()">Schedule</button>
 </my-dialog>
```

here is the function to be called in ng-model.

```
 $scope.ViewSchedule = function () {
        console.log('ViewSchedule function call');
        .....
        return obj.Schedule();
    };
```

here is the directive:

```
 return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            replace: true,
            transclude: false,
            priority: 100,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,

            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

                var getDialogTemplate = $attrs.myDlgTemplateUrl;

                $scope.openDialog = function (confirmationAction) {
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        backdrop: 'static',
                        templateUrl: getDialogTemplate,
                        controller: "myDialogCtrl",
                        resolve: {
                            dialogData: function () {
                                return {
                                    dlgData: $attrs.ngModel
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                        return confirmationAction();
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    }])

    .controller('myDialogCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$modalInstance', 'dialogData', function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, dialogData) {

        $scope.dialogData = dialogData.dlgData;

        $scope.onOk = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
        $scope.onCancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }])
```

Here is the dialog template :

```
   <tr ng-repeat="item in dialogData">
            <td>{{item.$index}}</td>
            <td>{{item.StartDate}}</td>
            <td>{{item.EndDate}}</td>

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-model establishes a 2 way data binding only needed if you are planning to alter the model if not a simple scope definition with one way  binding or a reference bound would do it

you currently have

```
scope:true
```

you can do

```
scope:{
   watchfor:'@result'
}
```

and inside the directive set a watcher

```
scope.$watch('watchfor',function(val){})
```

in your direcitve declaration you could have.

```
<my-dialog my-dlg-template-url="/app/ScheduleDlg.html" result="ViewSchedule()"> </my-dialog>
```

and set this in your directive template

```
        <button ng-click="openDialog()">Schedule</button>

unless you want it linked to your parent scope.
```

Comment: will the "result" has returned value from the function or will it call the function? and how can I use it to display values in my dialog?

Comment: The wa is used there will be the function returned values and then that   result will map to scope.watch for variable. Wichita you can use in your dialog template